# how to use the method then in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on app where Users have user roles. The class below checks the inscription of users. The issue is I keep getting this error The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.

```
class _InscriptionState extends State<Inscription> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User courentUtil;

  //Collection Utilisateur depuis firebase

  final CollectionReference  collectionUtil = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utilisateurs');

  String nom = ' ';
  String prenom = ' ';
  String email = ' ';
  String numero = ' ';
  String motdePasse = ' ';
  String ConfMP = ' ';
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then((User util) {
        setState((){
            this.courentUtil = util;
      });
    });

    String _idUtil(){
       if(courentUtil != null){
        return courentUtil.uid;
          } else {
            print("pas d'utilisateur courant");
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 0.18.0:

```
Accessing the current user via currentUser() is now synchronous via the currentUser getter.
```

So you you dont need to user then to get the value, just do:

```
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```